# CSS fixed horizontal center element

Tags: html, css

How do I horizontal center an element and keep fixed at the same time?

Is this possible?  Another elements on page can use html or css.

example:

[image: example]

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code; we can't guess your mark-up and CSS from a picture; it's very helpful to provide a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show it in action.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

try `margin: auto;`. It centers horizontally but the element must have a width.